# value selection in sql request does not work

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a [demo version of my script](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a5dfb650b5b944a79e47433d58eb569e).

In the query I indicate that I am looking for an ID where `i.VALUE_STRING = 'aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25'` but it replies, shows the ID and not only my conditions but also the extra IDs, I get an ID where `i.VALUE_STRING = 'aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a26e03f49835a26`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
ID       VALUE_NUMBER   VALUE_STRING                          INFO
4680828  1578109515974  aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25  95888137 MY_IDENT
4680704 1578109515974   aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25  95888137 MY_IDENT
```

Comment: Providing a fiddle is great, but your question needs to include the relevant code and other information. (Also snippets are not appropriate for SQL, or data display.)

Comment: Whatever I am seeing is only input Id is in the result set.No other IDs. Are you sure you are getting other IDs also.

Comment: Your CTE is restricted by `value_string`, but the main query isn't. Look at the data that's actually returned from `txn`; and then run `select * from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION where value_number = 1578109515974`. Does that show you where the problem might be?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes I understood it, the problem is that I can't solve it, I have been searching for an answer to this question for several hours. And I asked to help here

Comment: It's doing what you told it too; `txn` finds all the info for that value string; then you're looking in `rep` for anything with the same value number. If you don't want to pick up extra records, why are you joining again at all - doesn't `txn` already have all the info you want? You don't really need a CTE (or even a subquery, probably) if that is the case. Again, please add relevant information and code by editing the question.

Comment: @AlexPoole  want to create a query from one table. But the query is a bit confusing and I can't get over it. I want to group the table with a request. I want to extract the "id" in which the common "reader" and all the "transactions" related to these readers!

Comment: I agree with @AlexPoole.  Inner select of the cte is returning almost all OP wants. Small difference with one value of column info... More details...

Comment: @АндрійГавриляк Please do understand that something that is maybe clear as day to you it is not to us. So... You will need to give us some example data with some simple examples that include wanted results and some explanations why...

Comment: @VBoka Look I have a table in it has a column "key", in this column there are different entries all of them are grouped together by the column "parents". There are three groups in my example (527241,527323,527322). I want to report where the fields are clustered not only by transaction but also by reader.
That is, the Hierarchy reports to be: 1-reader, 2-transaction, 3-parents.

Comment: @VBoka I understand that adding another checker to the reader in the second part of the request, here in this "LEFT join txn
   on rep.VALUE_NUMBER = txn.transaction_value_number ". The whole mistake is that this is a transaction check, but this transaction may be in the second reader!

Comment: @АндрійГавриляк - but you haven't explained why you are doing that final join - you already have the relevant transaction in `txn` (for 527241,527323) so what extra information are you expecting/trying to pick up by joining back to the base table? If we can't understand why you're doing something, we don't know if that's because you have a reason we don't know about, or if it's really not needed.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, this is not my complete request, here is my complete request, for merging with other tables https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b3c1dc74c413e76b8364a3f6b7b60f86

Comment: @AlexPoole I need to add a check where I use a connection to check not only the transaction but also whether the reader in it is right for me. But I don't know how to do it

Comment: I still don't see why you need to join to `rep` when you have all the info you need already in `txn` - that join doesn't seem to add anything except confusion. You could make the query from my answer a CTE, and join from that to other tables (but *not* to `rep`) - and as a bonus you wouldn't need to have a `group by`. [Something like this?](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b3440690496719f486f904211fcf746)

Comment: @VBoka https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908608/fill-in-the-missing-data-with-a-query-in-oracle Please see, I explained in more detail here)

Comment: @AlexPoole  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908608/fill-in-the-missing-data-with-a-query-in-oracle Please see, I explained in more detail here)

Comment: @VBoka thank you, you understand me) and could you still look at another case, maybe you chose me how to do it) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've said in comments you're over-complicating things; you can get the result you want from just modifying the inner query from your CTE:

```
 SELECT o.id,
        o.VALUE_NUMBER,
        i.VALUE_STRING,
        MIN (TRIM (
                   v.VALUE_STRING
                || ' '
                || v.VALUE_NUMBER
                || ' '
                || x.VALUE_STRING
                || ' '
                || c.VALUE_STRING)
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY o.VALUE_NUMBER,
                                 i.VALUE_STRING)
           AS INFO
   FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  o
        LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  i ON o.parent = i.parent
        LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  v
           ON     i.parent = v.parent
              AND v.KEY = 'truck1'
        LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  x
           ON     i.parent = x.parent
              AND x.KEY = 'item_name'
        LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  c
           ON     x.parent = c.parent
              AND c.KEY = 'truck2'
  WHERE     i.key = 'reader'
        AND i.VALUE_STRING =
             'aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25'
        AND o.key = 'transaction'
        AND o.value_number <> 0
        AND TRIM (
                  v.VALUE_STRING
               || ' '
               || v.VALUE_NUMBER
               || ' '
               || x.VALUE_STRING
               || ' '
               || c.VALUE_STRING)
               IS NOT NULL
```

which gets:

```
     ID | VALUE_NUMBER  | VALUE_STRING                         | INFO             
------: | :------------ | :----------------------------------- | :----------------
4680828 | 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | 95888137 MY_IDENT
4680704 | 1578109515974 | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | 95888137 MY_IDENT
```

Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=00cc6ed5c52ac6f47e83154e86168924)

Even that might be more complicated than necessary but it's hard to tell. And there may be reasons for the CTE and final outer join back to the same table, but if so those haven't been explained, and at the moment those are just introducing the extra rows you say you don't want.

At the moment your `txn` CTE gets basically the same data as above:

```
...
select * from txn;

TRANSACTION_VALUE_NUMBER | READER_VALUE_STRING                  |      ID | INFO             
:----------------------- | :----------------------------------- | ------: | :----------------
1578109515974            | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | 4680828 | MY_IDENT         
1578109515974            | aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25 | 4680704 | 95888137 MY_IDENT
```

You are then looking up all of the `transaction` rows from the base table with that `value_number`, which is where it finds the 'extra' ID you aren't expecting:

```
select * from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION where value_number = 1578109515974

     ID | VALUE_NUMBER  | VALUE_STRING | KEY         | PARENT
------: | :------------ | :----------- | :---------- | :-----
4680704 | 1578109515974 | null         | transaction | 527241
4680828 | 1578109515974 | null         | transaction | 527323
4680123 | 1578109515974 | null         | transaction | 527322
```

and then you're mixing the data from those rows with the data from `txn` to get your confusing result.

---

You can still use this to join to other tables; something like this perhaps:

```
WITH txn AS (
     SELECT o.id,
            o.VALUE_NUMBER,
            i.VALUE_STRING,
            MIN (TRIM (
                       v.VALUE_STRING
                    || ' '
                    || v.VALUE_NUMBER
                    || ' '
                    || x.VALUE_STRING
                    || ' '
                    || c.VALUE_STRING)
                ) OVER (PARTITION BY o.VALUE_NUMBER,
                                     i.VALUE_STRING)
               AS INFO
       FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  o
            LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  i ON o.parent = i.parent
            LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  v
               ON     i.parent = v.parent
                  AND v.KEY = 'truck1'
            LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  x
               ON     i.parent = x.parent
                  AND x.KEY = 'item_name'
            LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  c
               ON     x.parent = c.parent
                  AND c.KEY = 'truck2'
      WHERE     i.key = 'reader'
            AND i.VALUE_STRING =
                 'aedef9f9-2e82-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25'
            AND o.key = 'transaction'
            AND o.value_number <> 0
            AND TRIM (
                      v.VALUE_STRING
                   || ' '
                   || v.VALUE_NUMBER
                   || ' '
                   || x.VALUE_STRING
                   || ' '
                   || c.VALUE_STRING)
                   IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT txn.id,
       txn.VALUE_NUMBER,      
       txn.VALUE_STRING,
       txn.parent,
       txn.INFO,
       evlog.id logid,
       evlog.cr_date,
       evlog.device_name device,
       to_char(date '1970-01-01' + rep.value_number/86400000, 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') ||' '|| nvl(trns.representation, '')  transaction_number,
       ev.deveventid event_id,
       nvl(evlog.description, ev.name) event_name,
       evlog.organization_name organization,
       '<img src="#IMAGE_PREFIX#app_ui/img/icons/apex-edit-view.png" class="apex-edit-view standalone-link" alt="Edit"><span class="photos-count"></span>' photos  
FROM txn
    LEFT  JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_EVENT_LOG evlog
       ON txn.parent = evlog.id
     LEFT JOIN IOT_DEVICE_EVENT ev
       ON evlog.device_event = ev.id
     LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_TRANSACTIONS trns
       ON txn.value_number = trns.name
order by  evlog.cr_date desc
```

Completely untested of course...

Comment: thank you, you understand me) and could you still look at another case, maybe you chose me how to do it) ??  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908608/fill-in-the-missing-data-with-a-query-in-oracle?noredirect=1#comment105944156_59908608

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a full answer, but may make things easier. Simple pivot returns desired output:

```
select tr_id, tr_vn, rd_vs, t1_vn, it_vs 
  from iot_stream s
  pivot (max(id) id, max(value_number) vn, max(value_string) vs 
         for key in ('transaction' tr, 'reader' rd, 'truck1' t1, 'item_name' it))
```

but it misses truck number in one case, so if you want to take it from other row with same reader value use:

```
nvl(t1_vn, max(t1_vn) over (partition by rd_vs)) t1_vn
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3619e47795274460c991777b8257d7b5)</sup>**

I shortened table name somewhat, my Oracle version is limited to 30 characters, but in dbfiddle I used full name.